# Database connectivity in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlyog

I want to connect my database that I have created in SQLyog (version 9.2.02) to Visual Studio 2010 using C#.

I am working on an Online Reservation project, and I am not finding the appropriate steps to do it.

How to proceed?

Comment: There is nothing special about ASP.NET when it comes to database connectivity. Can you connect to the database from some other kind of application? Then do it the same way for ASP.NET.

Comment: -1 : try explaining what you have tried so far, what exact error messages you encountered, etc. Your question is too general to be useful at present.

Comment: no this is my first encounter with database connectivity.i just want a basic idea how to proceed.i used ado.net for connectivity but while using initial catalog in my connection string it is showing an error as keyword not defined.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean how do you connection to a MySQL database you created using SQLyog?

Check out this article on the MySQL site:

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/dotnet/

It provides three different connectors:

1.) The ODBC.NET Solution - MyODBC Driver

2.) Using MySQL Native .NET Providers

3.) Using the OLEDB.NET Solution - MyOLDDB Provider

You can get the connector library here:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/5.0.html